# On the existence of Graph Monomorphism

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

A graph monomorphism is an injective graph homomorphism. Determining existence of Graph monomorphism between graph pairs is computationally hard.

Assume we talk only about classes of undirected graphs with no loops and no multiple edges.

What are some of the broad techniques that have been used to show existence of monomorphisms between pairs of structured graphs?

Also, for classes of graphs that have 'explicit' homomorphisms, what techniques have been used to show that they can be extended to monomorphisms?

Is there a survey from an algebraic or spectral view point?

(Note that there are standard results which prohibit homomorphisms such as the no homomorphism lemma. My question is on graphs which pass these tests.)

Comment: Could you tell us what notion of graph you have in mind? Multiple edges between vertices? Directed or not? Can vertices have loops?

Comment: @ToddTrimble Updated the question to clarify your comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "graph monomorphism is computationally hard"? Does "graph monomorphism" mean the problem of determining, for a pair of graphs, whether there is a monomorphism from one to the other?

Comment: Determining whether there is a monomorphism between two simple graphs (i.e. undirected, without loops, without multiple edges) is known as the subgraph isomorphism problem for simple graphs.
This problem is NPC (there is an obvious reduction from the clique problem) in its full generality. There are, however, known polynomial (mostly decomposition-based) algorithms for some special classes of graphs.

Comment: Generally, for NPC problems, the knowledge that there is a solution does not help much in finding the solution. For let us assume that there is an algorithm $A$ that works in a polynomial time on the instances that are known to have solutions (let me call these instances "positive"). This means that there exist constants $k, c$ such that running time of $A(x)$ on positive instances $x$ is bounded by $c+|x|^k$. One may then design a new algorithm $B$ that given *any* instance $x$ simulates $A$ up to $c+|x|^k$ steps and if $A$ terminates, outputs the answer returned by $A$, and "No" otherwise.

Comment: @MichalR.Przybylek This question is not really about comp complexity. Could you explain "polynomial (mostly decomposition-based) algorithms for some special classes of graphs"?

Comment: JAS,I tried to convince you that knowing that there is a solution cannot help in finding solution. Therefore, there cannot be any special techniques. As for the sentence about polynomial algorithms: I hardly recall (but may be wrong) that the problem is easy for classes related to bounded tree-width/bandwidth. Check for example this paper: "Subgraph isomorphism, log-bounded fragmentation, and graphs of (locally) bounded treewidth". There are also some works on subgraph isomorphism problem, when one graph is fixed ("Subgraph Isomorphism in Planar Graphs and Related Problems" by D. Eppstein).

Comment: @MichalR.Przybylek "there cannot be any special techniques." I understand that for general classes. May be I should word differently.